# How to remove an old commit in none master branch after cherry-pick?

Tags: git, commit, git-cherry-pick

In master branch I have below commits:

```
A-B-C-D-HEAD
```

In branch "test" I have:

```
A
```

I did:

```
git cherry-pick <SHA FOR COMMIT C>
```

However, I don't want commit B on "test" branch. How can I ignore that? so that test branch end up like:
A-C

Comment: Do you only want commit C on the test branch? Or A and C on the test branch?

Comment: You need to edit your question to show where your test branch is relative to the other commits.

Comment: If you all did is `git cherry-pick <SHA FOR COMMIT C>` when the `HEAD` of `test` is still pointed at `A` (i.e. you didn't do any merge), you should only end up with just `A-C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this: (Assuming master points to D)
1. (master) `git-checkout -b test`
2. (test) `git rebase -i`
You will have a list of commits like:

```
pick b6e7d38 A
pick 263b0cc B
pick 6bcea1d C
pick 6kdf8gd D
```

Just delete the commit that you don't want (B and D here). Save and continue, It will be omitted while rebasing.

Comment: If she rebases and removes the commits, they will be gone for good from master. She wants them on master but not on test.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree with your point.Please refer this below doc
You can combine your commits by rebase and squash the ones you dont need. 

Refere this: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Comment: I agree, your approach was perfectly alright but on a wrong branch. If you rebase the master branch and delete D and B, then they will be gone for good. You approach is correct if she did that while on test branch where test has originated from master pointing to D.

I edited the answer as rebase -i master would have been messy for her

Answer (score 0):

The best option according to me would be `git format-path`.

Step1: (master) `git format-patch -2` 
Step2: (master) `git checkout -b test <SHA of Commit-A>`
Step3: (test) `git am 0002-Commit-Msg-of-C`

You are good to go!

Explanation: Step1 will create 2 patch-files, one for commit D and one for C. In Step3 you are applying the patch(changes) made while commit-C over A(test points to A, step2)

Hope this helps!

PS: This will work if your changes in B are unrelated to changes in C.

Comment: All that's needed is `git cherry-pick`.